# How to add new element to arraylist of linked list Java

Tags: java

I'm implement a hashing table using `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` as bucket.

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<node>> db = new ArrayList<LinkedList<node>>();
```

How can I add new element in this `ArrayList`.
Would it be something like this?

```
this.db.add(hash, element);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like this:

```
LinkedList<node> tmp = new LinkedList<node>();
tmp.add(new node());
this.db.add(tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be

```
db.get(hash).add(element);
```

of course requiring that your buckets (`LinkedList`s) have been instantiated already.